# The method findViewById(int) is undefined

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to code a little app which allows me to grab an external JSON file and parse it. I got this to work, however it wont work if I try to execute it in the background as an `AsyncTask`. Eclipse gives me the error

> The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type LongOperation

in this line:

> TextView txtView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new LongOperation().execute();
    }
}


class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final Context LongOperation = null;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL json = new URL("http://www.corps-marchia.de/jsontest.php");
            URLConnection tc = json.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(0);
                    TextView txtView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                    txtView1.setText(jo.getString("text") + " - " + jo.getString("secondtest"));
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.LongOperation, "Malformed URL Exception: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.LongOperation, "IO Exception: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.LongOperation, "JSON Exception: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(LongOperation);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMessage("Working...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
    }    

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `AsyncTask` in one of the other answers is flawed.  The progress dialog is being created every time within `publishProgress`, and the reference to the dialog is not visible outside the method.  Here is my attempt:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new LongOperation().execute();
    }
    class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog pd = null;
        TextView tv = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            tv = Main.this.findViewById(R.id.textvewid);
            pd = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
            pd.setMessage("Working...");
            // setup rest of progress dialog
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //perform existing background task
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            pd.dismiss();
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. ive tried this and its giving me the error "No enclosing instance of the type Main is accessible in scope" in the lines 53 and 54. here is the source with numbered lines: http://paste2.org/p/1244101 thanks in advance

Comment: Ah, you have created it as a separate class, just in the same Java file.  In my example the `LongOperation` is a *member* class, and so has access to the instance that encloses it.  In your code `LongOperation` is a top-level class, so `Main.this` is out of scope.  To fix the problem, you can either move `LongOperation` so that it is a member class, or create a constructor for `LongOperation` that accepts a `Context`.  You would then use `new LongOperation(this).execute();` to kick off the task.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you should do to make it work as you want. Use onPostExecude()

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new LongOperation(this).execute();
    }
}


class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Main longOperationContext = null;

    public LongOperation(Main context) {
        longOperationContext = context;
        Log.v("LongOper", "Konstuktor");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.v("doInBackground", "inside");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL json = new URL("http://www.corps-marchia.de/jsontest.php");
            URLConnection tc = json.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(0);
                    Log.v("line = ", "jo.getString() ="+jo.getString("text"));
                    sb.append(jo.getString("text") + " - " + jo.getString("secondtest")).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("Error", "URL exc");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("ERROR", "IOEXECPTOIn");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("Error", "JsonException");
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.v("onPostExe", "result = "+result);
      TextView txtView1 = (TextView)longOperationContext.findViewById(R.id.textView01);
      txtView1.setText(result);


    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(longOperationContext);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMessage("Working...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
    }    

}
```

Comment: thanks! this almost did it! however i cant get the progressdialog working properly. i moved it to onPreExecute and it shows up, but cant seem to be able to remove it. ive tried pd.hide() in onPostExecute() but it says "pd cannot be resolved". heres the code: [link](http://paste2.org/p/1243854) thanks in advance

Comment: Make pd init in constructor , and pd.show in onPreExecute() and remove it in onPostExecute(). And try to use pd.dismiss() rather than pd.hide(). It's better. Here you have code - > http://paste2.org/p/1244908

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do something which won't work. First of all you are inside of a class that extends `AsyncTask` so you won't have that method available as it is a method of the class `Activity`.

The second problem is that you are trying to do UI stuff in a method that is not synchronized with the UI thread. That is nothing you would want to do.

Process your JSON response in the `doInBackground` method and pass the result to the `onPostExecute` method where you will be able to handle UI stuff as it is synchronized with the UI thread.

The current setup you have will not make it easier for you to handle what you are trying to do anyway. You could make your `LongOperation` class a private class of your `Activity` class and define the `TextView` as a instance member. Grab it off the layout using `findViewById` inside of your `OnCreate` and modify (set text or whatever)  inside the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask`.

I hope it is somewhat clear what I meant.

Comment: ive tried putting "TextView txtView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);" in the onPostExecute method but im still getting the same error. is that what you meant? can you show me an example of what you mean? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

findViewById is method in Activity class. You should pass instance of your activity to your LongOperation when you create it. Then use that instance to call findViewById.

Comment: Passing an instance of your `Activity` class somewhere is highly dangerous if you don't know what you are doing as you might end up leaking the entire activity!