# Creating a class in android findViewById() method is undefiend - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, findviewbyid

I have created a new class called commentasync. I placed a findViewById() inside of the doInBackground section and it gives me an error. Here is basically what my code is. The findViewById doesnt work and it wont let me verify a new View. A textView or button will come up as an error as well.

```
    public class commentAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


  UserFunctions userFunctions;


    // JSON Response node name
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_STATE = "state";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static String KEY_COMMENT = "comment";
    private static String KEY_COMMENT_ID = "commentID";
    private static String KEY_NUMBER_OF_COMMENTS = "numberOfComments";
    private static String KEY_POSTED_AT = "posted_at";
    private static String KEY_VERIFY = "verify";
    private static String KEY_OFFSET_NUMBER = "offsetNumber";


    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    String usernameforcomments = db.getUserDetails();



     registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collectComment_error);
     int verify = 1;
     int verify2 = 1;
     String offsetNumber = "null";
     LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.commentSection);





    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
return null;






 UserFunctions CollectComments = new UserFunctions();
 JSONObject json = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);




     int commentCycle = 1;

      // check for comments  
      try {  
     if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
         registerErrorMsg.setText("");
         String res2 = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
         if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 

             String numberOfComments = json.getString(KEY_NUMBER_OF_COMMENTS);


             String offsetNumberDb = db.getOffsetNumber();


            int numberOfComments2 = Integer.parseInt(numberOfComments) - Integer.parseInt(offsetNumberDb);
            offsetNumber = offsetNumberDb;

             //if comment number is less than 15 or equal to 15
             if(numberOfComments2 <= 15){




             while (commentCycle <= numberOfComments2){

                 JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);


                LinearLayout commentBox = new LinearLayout(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                 commentBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_bg);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
                commentBox.setPadding(0,0,0,10);
                 commentBox.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                 linear.addView(commentBox, layoutParams);

                 RelativeLayout commentBoxHeader = new RelativeLayout(this);
                commentBoxHeader.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                 commentBoxHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_bg);
                commentBoxHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_header);
                commentBox.addView(commentBoxHeader);

                 TextView plateView = new TextView(this);
                plateView.setText(json2.getString(KEY_PLATENUMBER));
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams plateViewParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                plateViewParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                 plateView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); 
                 plateView.setTextSize(15);
                 plateView.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
                 plateView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                commentBoxHeader.addView(plateView, plateViewParam);

                TextView usernameView = new TextView(this);
                usernameView.setText("Posted by: " + json2.getString(KEY_USERNAME));
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams usernameViewParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                usernameViewParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                 usernameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                 usernameView.setPadding(5, 5, 10, 5);
                 usernameView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                commentBoxHeader.addView(usernameView, usernameViewParam);


                TextView commentView = new TextView(this);
                commentView.setText(json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT));
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams commentViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                commentViewParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 20);
                commentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_bg);
                 commentView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); 
                commentBox.addView(commentView, commentViewParams);

                TextView descriptionView = new TextView(this);
                descriptionView.setText(json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT));
                descriptionView.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 20);
                descriptionView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                descriptionView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); 
                commentBox.addView(descriptionView);

                RelativeLayout commentBoxButtons = new RelativeLayout(this);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams commentBoxButtonsParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                 commentBox.addView(commentBoxButtons, commentBoxButtonsParam);

                Button btnTag1 = new Button(this);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnTag1Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                btnTag1Param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                 btnTag1.setText("Go to " + json2.getString(KEY_PLATENUMBER));
                 btnTag1Param.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                 btnTag1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_post);
                 btnTag1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                 btnTag1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                 btnTag1.setPadding(8, 5, 8, 5);
                 btnTag1.setId(verify);
                 commentBoxButtons.addView(btnTag1, btnTag1Param);

                 Button btnTag2 = new Button(this);
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnTag2Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                btnTag2Param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                 btnTag2.setText("Go to " + json2.getString(KEY_USERNAME));
                 btnTag2Param.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                 btnTag2.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                 btnTag2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_post);
                 btnTag2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                 btnTag2.setPadding(8, 5, 8, 5);
                 btnTag2.setId(verify2); 
                 commentBoxButtons.addView(btnTag2, btnTag2Param);

                verify2 = verify2 + 1;
                verify = verify + 1; 
                offsetNumber = json2.getString(KEY_OFFSET_NUMBER);
                commentCycle = commentCycle + 1;

         }//end while
             }//end if comment number is less than or equal to 15


             //if comment number is greater than 15
             if(numberOfComments2 > 15){
                 int commentCycle2 = 0;
             while(commentCycle2 <= 15){
                 commentCycle2 = commentCycle2 + 1; 
                 JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);


                LinearLayout commentBox = new LinearLayout(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  commentBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_bg);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
                commentBox.setPadding(0,0,0,10);
                  commentBox.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                  linear.addView(commentBox, layoutParams);

                  RelativeLayout commentBoxHeader = new RelativeLayout(this);
                 commentBoxHeader.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                  commentBoxHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_bg);
                 commentBoxHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_box_header);
                 commentBox.addView(commentBoxHeader);



                TextView usernameView = new TextView(this);
                usernameView.setText("Posted by: " + json2.getString(KEY_USERNAME));
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams usernameViewParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                usernameViewParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                  usernameView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                  usernameView.setPadding(5, 5, 10, 5);
                  usernameView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                commentBoxHeader.addView(usernameView, usernameViewParam);


                TextView commentView = new TextView(this);
                commentView.setText(json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT));
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams commentViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                commentViewParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 20);
                commentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_bg);
                  commentView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); 
                commentBox.addView(commentView, commentViewParams);

                TextView descriptionView = new TextView(this);
                descriptionView.setText(json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT));
                descriptionView.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 20);
                descriptionView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                descriptionView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); 
                commentBox.addView(descriptionView);

                RelativeLayout commentBoxButtons = new RelativeLayout(this);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams commentBoxButtonsParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  commentBox.addView(commentBoxButtons, commentBoxButtonsParam);

                Button btnTag1 = new Button(this);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnTag1Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                btnTag1Param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                  btnTag1.setText("Go to " + json2.getString(KEY_PLATENUMBER));
                  btnTag1Param.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                  btnTag1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_post);
                  btnTag1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                  btnTag1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                  btnTag1.setPadding(8, 5, 8, 5);
                  btnTag1.setId(verify);
                  commentBoxButtons.addView(btnTag1, btnTag1Param);

                  Button btnTag2 = new Button(this);
                  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnTag2Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                btnTag2Param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                  btnTag2.setText("Go to " + json2.getString(KEY_USERNAME));
                  btnTag2Param.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                  btnTag2.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                  btnTag2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_post);
                  btnTag2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                  btnTag2.setPadding(8, 5, 8, 5);
                  btnTag2.setId(verify2); 
                  commentBoxButtons.addView(btnTag2, btnTag2Param);

                verify2 = verify2 + 1;
                verify = verify + 1; 
                offsetNumber = json2.getString(KEY_OFFSET_NUMBER);
                commentCycle = commentCycle + 1;




             }//end while cycle <= 15

             db.resetOffsetTable();
             db.addOffset(Integer.parseInt(offsetNumber));

             }//end if comment number is greater than 15













            }//end if key is == 1
         else{
             // Error in registration
             registerErrorMsg.setText(json.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
         }//end else
     }//end if
 } //end try

 catch (JSONException e) { 
     e.printStackTrace();
 }//end catch   










    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) has no `findViewById` method defined. Check the reference page to see what methods you can use. `Activity` class would have that though, so you might want to create the `AsyncTask` inside an `Activity` or pass a view to it.

If you're going to create an `AsyncTask` inner class, then you can have:

```
registerErrorMsg = (TextView) YourActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.collectComment_error);
```

Comment: How can I put this inside of an activity? When I do all i get are errors even worse than when its in its own class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979454/the-method-findviewbyidint-is-undefined. Make sure you read all the answers, for it will give you a better understanding on how you should use `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? **Is your AsyncTask class outside your Activity class?**

**If yes**, as Voicu said, you should create your AsyncTask as an inner class in your Activity. After doing that, you can use findViewById() method. Have a look at the following example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    //Some code

    public class commentAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {
        //Hurray! Can use findViewById() here!
    }

    //Some more code
}
```

**If no**, I am waiting for more information.

---

***UPDATE:***

Answering to your first comment, this works for me well:

```
public class A extends Activity {

    public class B
    {

    }

    class C
    {

    }
}
```

I am not sure why it is not working for you but as I remember I had similar problem before...

Comment: Yes, I you were correct I needed to put the class inside of my activity. But when I place this class inside my activity it says commentAsync is an error and cant be public?

Comment: Try to delete public declaration (it helped me before).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are tying to say

        public class DashboardActivity extends Activity implements commentAsync {

public class commentAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
            {
                
            }

Comment: no no no, implements is there just because I used some interfaces, just forget about it (I delete it from my answer). Also, read this: Q. Why can't two public classes be defined in one class scope in java?

A. Just the way the language is designed. Once you get used to it, you'll find it helps you organize your code.

Comment: Okay I understand now. I removed the public class and it works but when i place the code LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.commentSection); inside the class it still says findViewById is not a method i can use.

Comment: delete "this." :) use LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.commentSection); As I told you before, AsyncTask doesn't have findViewById() method, which mean that you can't write this.findViewById(). You are welcome :) P.S I see that you are new here, like me. But now maybe I know more or less how stackoverflow works. First of all always write what type of error you get, try to find solution by your own before posting a question, and always accept answer if it solves your problem.