# Context cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I started looking into Android development a few days ago. I'm trying to fetch data from a REST API, and I'm using the AsyncTask class to do the HTTP transaction. The issue is, I'm unable to fetch the context for my main activity in order to find my ListView and assign the content to it in onPostExecute().

Here is MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new DownloadMediaList(this).execute();
    }
}
```

And here is DownloadMediaList.java:

```
public class DownloadMediaList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Media>> {

    ListView listView = null;
    Context mainContext = null;

    public DownloadMediaList(Context main){
        this.mainContext = main;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        listView = (ListView) mainContext.this.findViewById(R.id.media_list);
    }

    // Operations that we do on a different thread.
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Media> doInBackground(Void... params){
        // Set an ArrayList to store the medias.
        ArrayList<Media> mediaList = new ArrayList<Media>();

        // Call the REST API and get the request info and media list in a JSONObject.
        RESTFunctions restRequest = new RESTFunctions();
        JSONObject jsonMedia = restRequest.getMediaList();

        // Try catch to catch JSON exceptions.
        try {
            // Store the media list into a JSONArray.
            JSONArray mediaArray = jsonMedia.getJSONArray("media");

            // Create an instance of media to store every single media later.
            Media media = new Media();

            // Loop through the JSONArray and add each media to the ArrayList.
            for (int i=0; i<mediaArray.length();i++){
                media = new Media();
                JSONObject singleMedia = mediaArray.getJSONObject(i);
                media.setTitle(singleMedia.getString("titre"));
                media.setYear(singleMedia.getString("annee"));
                media.setLength(singleMedia.getString("duree"));
                mediaList.add(media);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Return the ArrayList.
        return mediaList;
    }

    // Operations we do on the User Interface. Synced with the User Interface.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Media> mediaList){
        // Set TextViews in ListViews here
    }
}
```

These classes are in two separate files.

This line in particular is giving me trouble:

```
listView = (ListView) mainContext.this.findViewById(R.id.media_list);
```

What am I doing wrong? It tells me Context cannot be resolved to a type, even though I've imported android.content.Context. I tried instantiating Context, but I can't do that either.

Comment: seems You don't need 'mainContext.this' Have You tried just (Activity)mainContext? Actually, context itself  doesn't have findViewById() method.

Comment: Whelp, looks like I read wrong and put in Context instead of Activity. But wouldn't this cause my activity to seep into another class?

Comment: I'm basing myself off the last answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979454/the-method-findviewbyidint-is-undefined . In this case, what should I do?

Comment: Avoid such casts, use `instanceOf`. Also, better hold a reference in constructor to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity class

```
    public interface TheInterface {
public void theMethod(ArrayList<Media> result);

 }
     }
```

Then

```
    DownloadMediaList task = new DownloadMediaList (MainAactivity.this,new TheInterface() {
             @Override
             public void theMethod(ArrayList<Media> result) {
                // result available here do whatever with list media
            }  
        });
```

Then in AsyncTask

```
Context mainContext = null;
TheInterface mlistener;
public DownloadMediaList(Context main,TheInterface listener){
    this.mainContext = main;
    mlistener = listener; 
}
```

Then in onPostExecute

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Media> mediaList){
   if (mlistener != null) 
    {
         mlistener.theMethod(mediaList);
    }
}
```

Edit:

As an alternative.

You can define interface in asycntask and have your activity class implement the interface.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with interfaces or how this functions at all, is there anywhere I can read on it?

Comment: @Sefam  read java docs on interface my oracle. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: @Sefam you can check this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. Here they use interface to pass value from fragment to parent activity.

Comment: I've always found that bicycle analogy to be awful. Why wouldn't you put methods inside a bicycle class anyway? And I'll try reading that page on fragments more closely.

Comment: bucycle analogy? i din't get it.

Comment: The javadocs on interface. It doesn't explain anything and uses shoddy analogies to try to explain why interfaces are useful, which just seems like another layer of verbosity to me. I'm used to C++.

Comment: Android is based on java. In any case if you find it difficult check the other link. There is not a lot of documentation on interface in the android docs.

Comment: Whelp. The solution just doesn't work, I think I'm just gonna wipe everything I have and start over. I've been at this since 7AM this morning, so frustrating. Done no progress at all. Nothing loads and I can't debug it.

Comment: Nah, the listview just doesn't load at all. The application runs, but nothing happens. I'm left with a blank screen. And I did add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> in my manifest. Not saying it's your fault. The rest of my code just isn't working and I'm sick of working with it. I inserted a bunch of breakpoints in my code and it just doesn't go through the HTTP request at all.

Comment: I'm going to post a new question. This is another matter entirely.

Comment: @Sefam yes that would be a lot better as this will lead to a long discussion.

Comment: Posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462226/asynctask-doesnt-doinbackground

Answer (score 1):

`Context`s don't have views, nor a `findViewById` method - try making your `mainContext` of type `Activity` instead.

Comment: I do realize I screwed up. The reason I tried using Context instead is because the last answer of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979454/the-method-findviewbyidint-is-undefined says clearly that if I don't know what I'm doing, my Activity could leak into other classes. Should I be doing this like that?

Comment: @Sefam - there's many ways to do it, but the important part is that you don't keep a long lasting reference to **any** `Context`. In your case, the `AsyncTask` (and its reference to your `Activity`) only live as long as your `AsyncTask` is running. Once it completes and your `onPostExecute` finishes, then the `AsyncTask` gets destroyed and so does its reference to your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
listView = (ListView) mainContext.this.findViewById(R.id.media_list);
```

with

```
listView = (ListView) mainContext.findViewById(R.id.media_list);
```

and the error should go away.

Comment: As the guy below said, there's to findViewById method in the Context class, and that I should replace it by Activity, but supposedly, I could leak my Activity into this class based on this last answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979454/the-method-findviewbyidint-is-undefined

Comment: @Sefam there is an alternative you can pass value back to your activity using an interface and then update ui.

Comment: Wouldn't that be unsynchronized and cause problems without a callback though?

Comment: @Sefam no its not and should not cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead add the AsyncTask as an inner class within your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;
    new DownloadMediaList(this).execute();
}

private class DownloadMediaList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Media>> {

ListView listView = null;




@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    listView = (ListView) context.findViewById(R.id.media_list);
}

// Operations that we do on a different thread.
@Override
protected ArrayList<Media> doInBackground(Void... params){
    // Set an ArrayList to store the medias.
    ArrayList<Media> mediaList = new ArrayList<Media>();

    // Call the REST API and get the request info and media list in a JSONObject.
    RESTFunctions restRequest = new RESTFunctions();
    JSONObject jsonMedia = restRequest.getMediaList();

    // Try catch to catch JSON exceptions.
    try {
        // Store the media list into a JSONArray.
        JSONArray mediaArray = jsonMedia.getJSONArray("media");

        // Create an instance of media to store every single media later.
        Media media = new Media();

        // Loop through the JSONArray and add each media to the ArrayList.
        for (int i=0; i<mediaArray.length();i++){
            media = new Media();
            JSONObject singleMedia = mediaArray.getJSONObject(i);
            media.setTitle(singleMedia.getString("titre"));
            media.setYear(singleMedia.getString("annee"));
            media.setLength(singleMedia.getString("duree"));
            mediaList.add(media);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return the ArrayList.
    return mediaList;
}

// Operations we do on the User Interface. Synced with the User Interface.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Media> mediaList){
    // Set TextViews in ListViews here
}
  }}
```

Comment: It is not mandatory to do that. But if the AsyncTask is not used else where you can have it within the same class.

Comment: I might be using this somewhere else later. What are my alternatives?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work, I need to cast the Context variable as an Activity, and I cannot cast MainActivity in that second class even when in the same file.